# Python list or pandas dataframe arbitrary indexing and slicing

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, slice

I have used both R and Python extensively in my work, and at times I get the syntax between them confused.

In R, if I wanted to create a model from only ***some*** features of my data set, I can do something like this:

```
subset = df[1:1000, c(1,5,14:18,24)]
```

This would take the first 1000 rows (yes, R starts on index 1), and it would take the 1st, 5th, 14th ***through*** 18th, and 24th columns.

I have tried to do any combination of `slice`, `range`, and similar sorts of functions, and have not been able to duplicate this sort of flexibility.  In the end, I just enumerated all of the values.

How can this be done in Python?

> Pick an arbitrary subset of elements from a list, some of which are selected individually (as in the commas shown above) and some selected sequentially (as in the colons shown above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a file of `index_tricks`, `numpy` defines a class instance that converts a scalars and slices into an enumerated list, using the `r_` method:

```
In [560]: np.r_[1,5,14:18,24]
Out[560]: array([ 1,  5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24])
```

It's an instance with a `__getitem__` method, so it uses the indexing syntax.  It expands `14:18` into `np.arange(14,18)`.  It can also expand values with `linspace`.

So I think you'd rewrite

```
subset = df[1:1000, c(1,5,14:18,24)]
```

as

```
df.iloc[:1000, np.r_[0,4,13:17,23]]
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a hidden tool to simplify things that I didn't know about!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iloc` for integer indexing in pandas:

```
df.iloc[0:10000, [0, 4] + range(13,18) + [23]]
```

As commented by @root, in Python 3, you need to explicitly convert `range()` to list by `df.iloc[0:10000, [0, 4] + list(range(13,18)) + [23]]`

Comment: As a side note, in Python 3 `range` is a generator, so it will need to be converted to a list: `list(range(13,18))`.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is correct, but overly messy and kludgy, IMHO... especially because I use python 3, which means I need to type in `list(range(13,18))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, The first square brackets filter. The second set of square brackets slice.

```
df[[0,4]+ range(13,18)+[23]][:1000]
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but overly "messy", IMHO.  This is something so common that I was hoping for a clean, easy-to-read and simple means.